# Regex extract characters between two string including delimiters

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to extract the text between two characters including the delimiters, but only the text without the delimiter is returned:

```
.+(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))
```

See [the current regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8XKxDW/3/).

**Example:**
`Some text (1990) (//Divulgação)`
**Should return:**
 `(//Divulgação)` (not `//Divulgação`)

Comment: if you need `(` and `)` in your match, why still use look around?

Comment: Should it also return `(1990)`? If not, what distinguishes the text you want to extract from that?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/8XKxDW/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract those substrings between `(` and `)` using

```
preg_match('~.*\K\([^()]*\)~s', $s, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qsWdwR/2).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the match buffer
- `\(` -  a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.